# Casting Int to Int64 in Haxe

Tags: casting, haxe, openfl, int64

When I set up primitive `Int` type to the `Int64` it works fine. I even can catch a constructor method in supplementary class `___Int64` that accepts **two** `Int` values -- high and low. It seems that this casting is static and even such code works perfectly:

```
var short:Int = 1111;
var long:Int64 = 2222;
long = short;
trace(long.high, long.low); // =0,1111
```

But when I'm setting up value from a field of `openfl.utils.Object` instance like:

```
var id:Int64 = data["id"];
```

where value of the `"id"` field either `Int` or `Int64` -- I've got an error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 1111 to haxe._Int64.___Int64.

Of course I can check the type of the field and properly instantiate an `Int64` from `Int`. But is there a neat solution to automate type casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [abstract type](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract.html) with [implicit casts](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html) from `Dynamic` (the return value of `openfl.utils.Object`'s array access get) to abstract the check away.

```
abstract AnyInt64(Int64) from Int64 to Int64 {
    @:from static function fromDynamic(d:Dynamic):AnyInt64 {
        if (Std.is(d, Int))
            return Int64.ofInt(cast d);
        if (Int64.is(d)) {
            var i:Int64 = cast d;
            return i;
        }
        throw "conversion error";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = new openfl.utils.Object();

data["int"] = 500;
var id:AnyInt64 = data["int"];

data["int64"] = Int64.make(1, 0);
var id2:AnyInt64 = data["int64"];
```

You would need to find a good way of dealing with attempted conversions that are not `Int` or `Int64` though (unless you only use those two types). Using `Null<Int64>` as the underlying type for `AnyInt64` + checking for `null` might work.

Comment: I have added conversion from `Float` as it is common type when creating objects with big numbers by JSON.